# Upgrade to Azure 2.2 SDK is causing roles to fail

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013

I have 3 worker roles and a web role in my project and I upgraded it to the new 2.2 SDK (required in VS2013).  Ever since the upgrade, all of the worker roles are failing and they instantly recycle as soon as they're started.

When the roles start, I'm getting these messages:

```
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime Information: 200 : Role entrypoint . CALLING                     OnStart()
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime Information: 202 : Role entrypoint . COMPLETED OnStart()
The thread 0x441c has exited with code 259 (0x103).
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime Information: 203 : Role entrypoint . CALLING   Run()
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime Warning: 204 : Role entrypoint . COMPLETED Run()  ==> ROLE RECYCLING INITIATED
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime Information: 503 : Role instance recycling is starting
The thread 0x2684 has exited with code 259 (0x103)
```

Two things draw my attention:

1. I've started to see a bunch of errors "Cannot find or open the PDB file."  But I don't know that this is directly relevant.
2. I'm using VS 2013 and while the project lists the SDK as 2.2, the references within the roles are the 2.1 versions.  Do I need to upgrade the components?  Why wouldn't the project upgrade these automatically when I pulled the project into VS as it only support 2.2?

Any thoughts on how to attach this are appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

Needed to manually change the references.

Comment: Yeah, I had this problem as well. When I manually changed the Azure references to point to the newest problem -- it all worked.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble... we have some people figuring out ways to make this better.

Comment: Jeff, add support for 1.8 under 2013! My group has 3rd party dependencies on 1.8 meaning we can't upgrade to 2013 :( Allowing only 2.2 is unfortunately a deal breaker for us :(

Comment: Any tips on how to do this?  I'm new to Azure and getting the exact error as above, but I'm not familiar with the process of upgrading SDK / changing references!